# How to encrypt a folder with machine ID

Tags: encryption, hash, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

I just signed up to for this question

I want a service that help me encrypt a folder with machine ID and for the user to open this folder he should go the the site or the app or whatsoever to get his password or the hash (I don't know what do you call it) but it must be unique for each device.

Thanks

Comment: what is the machine ID?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, *what is your question?*